# Can we import Apex method from Managed Package into LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, managed-package

I have **Managed Package** which is installed in my **Dev Org**.

This package contains some **Apex Methods** which I want to import into my LWC in the Dev Org.

The **Apex Class** and **Method** marked as `global` in the **Package org**.

```java
global class GlobalUtility {
    global static Boolean isUserLicenced(Id userId) {
        Boolean isUserLicenced = false;
        // do some logic
        return isUserLicenced ;
    }
}
```

However I still **can't import** them into my LWC, i have tried different variants:

```javascript
// should be the correct one
import isUserLicenced from '@salesforce/apex/packageName.GlobalUtility.isUserLicenced'; 
// however it gives "Unable to find Apex action method referenced as 'packageName.GlobalUtility.isUserLicenced'." error

// not working as it search for local classes
import isUserLicenced from '@salesforce/apex/GlobalUtility.isUserLicenced'; 
// not working as it search for local "packageName__GlobalUtility" class
import isUserLicenced from '@salesforce/apex/packageName__GlobalUtility.isUserLicenced';
```

In the docs: [Component Namespaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_namespace), I see that:

> A custom Lightning web component can't access a Lightning web
> component or module in a custom namespace when running in an org
> that’s using Lightning Locker instead of Lightning Web Security

I do have **Lightning Web Security** enabled !!

However it is about **other LWC's and modules** from package, not about Apex Classes !!

So my **Question** is:

**Can we import Apex method from Managed Package into our local LWC ??**

*Any help will be appreciated,

thanks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never gotten to work, either, but conceptually, you'd just write a local class to bridge the gap:

```
public class MyUtils {
  @AuraEnabled public static Boolean isUserLicensed(Id userId) {
    return packageName.GlobalUtility.isUserLicensed(userId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, I just understand I am missing "@AuraEnabled" on the Global method declaration. Will try with it. However your variant is pretty good.

Comment: @VitaliiDehnerys Yeah, now you mention it, I see that, too. That was probably my problem back in the day, too.

Comment: Just to confirm, I added "@AuraEnabled" to the Global method declaration and it works perfectly.